# how to prevent a user to access API's when a admin deactivate him but at the time of deactivation he's already logged in

Tags: node.js, jwt

I have one user who is logged in, at the same time **ADMIN** deactivate him.
As he is logged in so he can access APIs so how can i prevent him ,i am using **jwt**

Comment: You can use force logout after deactivating the account of that user with the warning showing that Her/His account has been blocked by admin and She/He can not operate further. This is the non-technical solution from my aspect. Please specify if you meant something else.

Comment: yeah that is a good idea, so  should i use socket for sending response to frontend.? or there is any other way.?

Comment: If you want to make it real-time, you can use a socket. but instead of using a socket for such a tiny requirement, you should wait for the user to perform the action ( i.e. when the user hits another API ) and then you can clear the user session (remove jwt token). As it also makes sense from user's point of view and good user experience.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the user id from the JWT. Then, when doing an operation in the API, check if the user is banned. If the user is banned, send a response back saying the user is banned. So, he will be 'deactivated'.

[image]

Comment: It's a good idea to keep a check on the user Id, but it's not a good to make a check on every API call as this can affect the user experience, code quality, and performance. So, It's better to put a check at some entry point such as login or dashboard.

Comment: i have to authenticate it on every API

Comment: I can't understand exactly why you want to authenticate every API but if you want to do it you can create a single middleware as a solution to authenticate every API and you have to make an API call through that middleware every time.

Comment: You could optimize it depending on the frequency of use and the importance of the actions. For example, you could add the checks to important things such as logging in, posting, adding a friend or commenting. But, you wouldn't do the checks in routes that could affect user experience. For example, getting a timeline, seeing comments or getting other standard data. So, the deactivated user could still see the data until he logs out/jwt expires.

Comment: Make sure you take caution for even if you force a log out from the device if an attacker has a verified jwt, the attacker could still operate on the server. However, from general user experience, it is definitely doable.

Answer (score -3):

https://github.com/esl/MongooseIM/issues/2235

As per the link above, there is no current way to ban/deactivate a user in the JWT Auth backend. However, if you were to delete the user, their user ID and token combination would cause for the same effect you are looking for: restricting their access to data.

In this case, I would delete the user instead of 'deactivating' them.